# How to get values from XML in java

Tags: java, android

First off all i want to get a value from XML in JAVA. I found some guides for this but every one is get all values from XML, i want just one value. Like this:

http://www.namazvaktim.net/xml/aylik/kayseri/kayseri.xml

This is the xml file i used. I want tı get a "ogle" for today's date. How can I do it ? Please help thank you.

Comment: have you already checked this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html

Comment: I readed this guide but i don't understand clearly. I think its hard to understand(I'm Turkish)

Comment: baby steps. were you able to instantiate the xml parser?